# Creating a new window or document window within Visual Studio programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-shell

So the problem I am having is related to creating a new window within Visual Studio such as the windows of the code editor. I have looked into using the DTE where you can use functions such as `EnvDTE.Document.NewWindow()` which will open a new window, but it is basically a replica of the window that contains the document.

I am struggling to find any resource for what I wish to do. My intention is to:

1. Understand how it is possible to create a new window or document window
2. Perform a similar action to what the "Peek Definition" window offers, whereby you open a window or document window within an existing window

Any suggestions, even if a resource I can take a look at would be greatly appreciated.